# typescript can't find node_modules

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-2015

Following on from TypeScript 101 QuickStart (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/tutorial.html) using Visual Studio 2015 and Node Tools for Visual Studio I tried importing 'winston' (after adding the npm module), but whatever path I use, Visual Studio says it can't find it.

How do I load external npm modules? (I'm using the CommonJs compile option).

Here's a screenshot:
[Visual Studio Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6ZO0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, install 'typings': `npm install typings --global`

Then, from the command line (in the root of your project), use typings to install the '.d.ts' file for 'winston':

```
typings install winston --source dt --save --global
```

The typings file will be added to your project in the `typings/global/winston` folder. Now add the following to the top of your 'app.js' file:

```
/// <reference path="typings/globals/winston/index.d.ts"/>
```

You can now use the winston logger like this:

```
var winston = require('winston');

winston.level = 'debug';
winston.debug('Debug messages are written to the console with the default logger.');
```

I added the 'fs-etxra' npm package to the project, then added the typings in the same way as above. The resulting project can be seen in the following screenshot:

[Visual Studio Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwzq9.png)